# Error occurred when create a remote on bitbucket using Xcode 10

Tags: bitbucket, xcode10

I just upgraded to Xcode 10. It has built-in bitbucket support.
I am already using bitbucket. Always do "add existing remote" after create a repository on the website. So no problem so far.
With Xcode 10, after I added my bitbucket account in Xcode preference, I tried "create (my app name) remote ..." for a test project. But I got "An unknown error occurred".
Tried both HTTPS and SSH, still not working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I figured it out by myself!

"Repository Name" was causing problem. When you create a remote in Xcode 10, the default name is your project name in Xcode. 
But after several test, I found that this name can NOT include upper case letters or spaces. 
After I changed the name to all lower cases, and replaced spaces with "_", everything is back to normal.
Interesting thing is I was able to create a repository on the website using upper case letters and spaces.

Edit:

Found the official reason:

The name is used as "slug".

The error message is:

Invalid slug. Slugs must be lowercase, alphanumerical, and may also contain underscores, dashes, or dots.

Xcode should have shown this to the developer to save them hours of frustrating.

Comment: wow, saved my day, same problem, same solution! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @schoeberlt, also double check on the website to make sure if it is private or public. Because in my case, all the projects were set to public even I picked "private" when I created the repository using Xcode.

Comment: You are great! I've found the same error and thank to you I've solved it

Comment: How did you figure that out? I checked Console but there was no such error - the only hint was a `received response, status 400 content K` (sic).